# Importing .py file onto another script to use variables from it where import file is run by "if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python-3.x

My original file `f1.py` is run by a `if __name__ == '__main__'` section in the code and within that section I store some variables. Now I am importing that file in a new file called f2.py.

I am importing it as : `From f1.py import *`

However, when I use some variables from f1.py in f2.py I get errors like 'variable not found' etc.

I have tried to do `os.system("python3 f1.py")` in `f2.py` and then see if I have access to these variables but still no luck.

As well as this I have also tried just simply calling import f1.py and still no luck.

Comment: Can you give the code for two files?

Comment: This is the reason `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks are used; to explicitly stop things being run when a module is imported. If you want to code to be run when it's imported you need it to be outside those blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code section inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` will only be executed if that python file is directly executed and not when imported as module. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

Simple solution is, the variables that you want to access inside f2 from f1 must be put outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'` section.

It is better if those values are got by calling a function inside f1. This minimizes the global variables.

Comment: So should I do os.system('python3 filename.py') and then will I have access to the variables inside 'filename.py' or would I still have to import the file after that

Comment: @AryanChordia No. You should move the bits you want to access outside the `if __name__ ...` block.